# coverting bigint into scientific number in hive

Tags: string, hive, hiveql, hue, scientific-notation

I am trying to convert bigint to scientific number in hive using cast function as below

```
select cast(805454539 as float) from table name;
```

Above query is giving me 805454528

However, I am looking for something like `8.05454539E8`

Answer (score 1):

To convert float to scientific notation string representation you can use printf() function (8 in this example - is the number of decimal places):

```
select printf('%1.8e',cast(805454539 as double))
```

result:

```
8.05454539e+08
```

Comment: i need result as 8.05454539E8 not 8.05454528e

Comment: actually doing float is converting value as well from 805454539 to 805454528.

Comment: @VijayAnde Use DOUBLE instead of FLOAT. Fixed the answer